# Getting system fonts

Tags: c++, winapi

I was wondering if there is a way to get the font of the following windows font inside the red box.

[image]

Is there any way to receive this font as a HFONT via a Win32 API function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably [the theme `TMT_HEADING1FONT` font](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773213(v=vs.85).aspx)? Just a guess.

Comment: DId this actually work? I haven't tried it myself; I'm not sure if you also need a part/state pair with that...

Comment: Somehow it didn't work for me, although I have windows themes enabled.

Comment: Hm... with [Theme Explorer](http://www.mctrl.org/tools.php) I see the font might be the `TMT_FONT` property of the `AeroWizard` control's `HeaderArea` part; try that specifically? (Note: `TMT_FONT` instead of `TMT_HEADING1FONT` as I originally thought; I now wonder what uses that property...) I'm not sure if that font size is identical but it *seems* close enough. The color should be `TMT_TEXTCOLOR`; that's also worth investigating to see if it's right.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this new suggestion? If not, I'll try it myself and post it as an answer if it works for me.

Comment: @andlabs Yes that would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done with uxtheme.dll, class `AeroWizard`, part `HeaderArea`. Either state 0 or state 1 (`NoMargins`) will work. Here's a sample, both using `DrawThemeText()` and manually. (Note that being a demonstration program, it does no error checking.)

```
// 20 june 2016
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#define STRICT
#define STRICT_TYPED_ITEMIDS
#define WINVER          0x0600
#define _WIN32_WINNT        0x0600
#define _WIN32_WINDOWS  0x0600
#define _WIN32_IE           0x0700
#define NTDDI_VERSION       0x06000000
#include <windows.h>
#include <uxtheme.h>
#include <vsstyle.h>
#include <vssym32.h>

HWND mainwin;
HWND edit;

void redraw(void)
{
    HDC dc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    WCHAR text[1024];
    HTHEME theme;
    LOGFONTW lf;
    HFONT font, oldfont;
    COLORREF color;
    SIZE extent;
    RECT r;

    dc = BeginPaint(mainwin, &ps);

    theme = OpenThemeData(mainwin, VSCLASS_AEROWIZARD);
    GetThemeFont(theme, dc, AW_HEADERAREA, 0, TMT_FONT, &lf);
    font = CreateFontIndirectW(&lf);
    GetThemeColor(theme, AW_HEADERAREA, 0, TMT_TEXTCOLOR, &color);

    GetWindowTextW(edit, text, 1024);
    GetThemeTextExtent(theme, dc, AW_HEADERAREA, 0,
        text, -1, 0, NULL, &r);
    extent.cx = r.right - r.left;
    extent.cy = r.bottom - r.top;

    SetWindowPos(edit, NULL,
        10, 10, 500, 20,
        SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_NOZORDER);

    r.left = 10;
    r.top = 40;
    r.right = 10 + extent.cx;
    r.bottom = r.top + extent.cy;
    DrawThemeText(theme, dc, AW_HEADERAREA, 0,
        text, -1, 0, 0, &r);

    oldfont = (HFONT) SelectObject(dc, font);
    color = SetTextColor(dc, color);
    r.top = r.bottom + 10;
    r.bottom = r.top + extent.cy;
    DrawTextW(dc, text, -1, &r, 0);
    SetTextColor(dc, color);
    SelectObject(dc, oldfont);
    DeleteObject(font);

    CloseThemeData(theme);
    EndPaint(mainwin, &ps);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK wndproc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_PAINT:
        redraw();
        return 0;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, TRUE);
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int main(void)
{
    WNDCLASSW wc;
    MSG msg;

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof (WNDCLASSW));
    wc.lpszClassName = L"mainwin";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = wndproc;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);
    RegisterClassW(&wc);

    mainwin = CreateWindowExW(0,
        L"mainwin", L"Main Window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        640, 200,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    edit = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        L"EDIT", L"Top is DrawThemeText(), bottom is manual",
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
        10, 10, 100, 100,
        mainwin, (HMENU) 100, NULL, NULL);

    ShowWindow(mainwin, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    UpdateWindow(mainwin);

    while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```